Constructing a pointwise convergent sequence of continuous functions
Given two sequences of real numbers $(\epsilon_n)\subseteq (0, 1)$ and $(s_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq (1, \infty)$ such that $\lim_n \epsilon_n=0$ and $(s_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is unbounded, is it possible to construct a sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and a Borel measure $\mu$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$, such that:

the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is (uniformly) bounded.
for each $t\in \mathbb{R}$, $\big\{ f_n(t) \big\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent and the $\mu$-measurable function $t\mapsto \lim_n f_n(t)$ is not constant. In other words, for $\mu$-almost each $t\in\mathbb{R}$, the set $\big\{s\in\mathbb{R}: \lim_n f_n(s)\neq \lim_n f_n(t) \big\}$ is not $\mu$-null.
for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and for any $t,s\in\mathbb{R}$, $\big\vert\, f_n(s)-f_n(t) \,\big\vert < \epsilon_n$ whenever $\vert\, t-s\,\vert < s_n$.

It is comparatively easy to construct such a sequence that only satisfies the first and third condition. For instance, consider a convergent sequence $(r_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq (0, \infty)$. Then let $h_n$ be the function that is constantly equal to $r_n$ in $[-s_n, s_n]$ and linear elsewhere. However, $(h_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ will converge pointwise (even uniformly) to the function that is constantly equal to $\lim_n r_n$, so $(h_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ fails. Any hints will be much appreciated.

Is $r_n$ supposed to be $\epsilon_n$ in the opening sentence?

Yes. Thanks for letting me know.

If a bounded function $h_n$ is constantly equal to $r_n$ in $[-s_n, s_n]$ and linear elsewhere then $h_n$ is constantly equal to $r_n$ everywhere.

Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of continuous functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ satisfying the third condition and convergent pointwise to a function $f$. Then $f$ is constant. Indeed, let $s,t$ be any real numbers. Suppose for a contradiction that $f(s)\ne f(t)$.
Since the sequence $(\epsilon_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to the zero, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $\epsilon_n<|f(s)-f(t)|/3$ for any $n>N$. Since the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges pointwise to the function $f$, there exists a natural number $N'\ge N$ such that for any $n>N$ we have $|f_n(s)-f(s)|<|f(s)-f(t)|/3$ and $|f_n(t)-f(t)|<|f(s)-f(t)|/3$.
Since the sequence $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is unbounded, there exists $n>N'$ such that $s_n>|s-t|$. By the third condition, $|f_n(s)-f_n(t)|<\epsilon_n$. Then
$$|f(s)-f(t)|\le |f(s)-f_n(s)|+|f_n(s)-f_n(t)|+|f_n(t)-f(t)|<$$ $$|f(s)-f(t)|/3+|f(s)-f(t)|/3+|f(s)-f(t)|/3=
|f(s)-f(t)|,$$
a contradiction.

Thank you for your answer! The third condition and the sequence of continuous functions will deny those possibilities. I was tempted to consider instead $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of Lebesgue integrable function. However, each Lebesgue integrable function can be approximated $L^{\infty}$-norm by a continuous function. At the end, it will lead to the similar contradiction.
